# Status Code 502 after adding "client_max_body_size" directive to Nginx

Tags: nginx, flask

I'm in need of increasing the threshold for uploading files. 10 MB will do it in my case.

So I added the directive to my nginx config file:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout  120000;
  location / {
    proxy_pass        http://users:5000;
    proxy_redirect    default;
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    client_max_body_size 10M;
    client_body_buffer_size 1000M;
  }
}
```

and also to the config on Flask backend:

```
class BaseConfig:
    ...
    MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH = 10 * 1024 * 1024
```

After updating I'm receiving status code 502. Without the `client_max_body_size` directive I get status code 413.

I `sh`ed into nginx server and ran `nginx -s reload` as it needs to be restarted for the new configs to take effect. Still getting 502 though.

nginx logs revealed:

```
[error] 26#26: *3 writev() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while sending request to upstream server
```

**Update:**

`stub_status` module revealed:

```
Active connections: 1 
server accepts handled requests
 14 14 13 
Reading: 0 Writing: 1 Waiting: 0
```

however this isn't very helpful as it's not indicating what is going
wrong.

What else do I need to check ?

Comment: Have you tried to monitor network connections before and after your changes?

Comment: @MacOS The thing is I'm using non-browser gui for frontend so I can't just hit F12 and head over to network tab. Is there any other way to see what's happening in network layer ?

Comment: @MacOS I've just learned about the stub_status module.

Comment: Added stub_status output to my question.